# Convert java.util.Date to Timestamp with Time Zone for PostgreSQL

Tags: java

I am trying to insert a date into my PostgreSQL db. Here is how I parse the date in my java application:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Date parsedTimeStamp = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

And in my PostgreSQL db. I have it as `Timestamp with Time Zone`. What is the ideal way to process and insert it?

Example of what the db expects `2017-09-09 07:15:33.451061+00`.

Comment: Actually, your database expects data, not a specifically formatted string. Let your JDBC driver worry about the technical implementation details of communicating that data. You should focus on Java objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat you use here translates a string, to a date, in your example, this must mean that the format you use id "yyyyMMdd" - for example 20171217 (today).

To create the string for the DB you need to take the opposite approach.
From a date object to a string.

You can create your own formatter for that (using your example)

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss.SSSSSSX");
    String text = formatter.format(date);
```

You can read more about formatting [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: I get the following exception : `Exception in thread "main" java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported field: ClockHourOfAmPm`

Comment: I updated the code. 
Note that the first line gets the current date (now)

Comment: But this Question asks specifically about parsing a date-only string, not getting the current moment. This Answer does not address the Question.

Comment: @BasilBourque, you're correct, I was giving the more general approach

Again - I linked to the formatting document, where you can find the following example:
      `LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
      String text = date.format(formatter);
      LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter);`

Comment: I needed to use this variant: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX` - in case it helps anyone.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 
    … , 
    LocalDate.parse( "20170909" , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE )  // Parse string into a date-only object, a `LocalDate` object.
             .atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) )             // Apply a time zone to determine the first moment of the day on that date, producing a `ZonedDateTime` object.
             .toInstant()                                             // Extract an `Instant` object, a moment always in UTC. This last step is not technically required, as your JDBC driver with Postgres should effectively do this on your behalf. But this line completes the demo conceptually.
) ;
```

- Work in **[objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_(object-oriented_programming)), not strings**, [between Java & database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity).
- Use only [***java.time***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes, not legacy date-time classes.
- Let your **[JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) + [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL)** do the heavy-lifting.
- Specify [**time zone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone).
- Always use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) security risks.

## Avoid legacy classes

The other Answers are outdated, using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## java.time

With a JDBC driver supporting JDBC 4.2 and later, you can exchange java.time objects with the Postgres server. No need for the java.sql date-time classes, nor the terrible `Date` and `Calendar` classes.

Persisting:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

…and retrieving:

```
Instant instant = myResultSet( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

In standard SQL, a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is a moment, a specific point on the timeline. In other words, a date, a time-of-day, and a time zone. In contrast, you have only a date, lacking the time-of-day and the time zone. You likely want to use the first moment of the day on that particular date in a particular time zone.

To change your date-only value to a moment, first make a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "20170909" , DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE ) ;
```

Next, call that `LocalDate` object’s `atStartOfDay` method while passing a `ZoneId`.

A time zone is required to lend meaning to a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.  For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Finally extract a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

At this point you can insert that `Instant` into database as discussed above.

## Objects, not strings

Your work will be easier if you learn to think in terms of objects rather than mere strings when exchanging data with a database from Java.

## `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`

By the way, be clear on how [Postgres uses the data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. The SQL standard defines this data type all too briefly, and databases vary in their implementation. The following describes behavior of Postgres versions 8, 9, and 10.

Any date-time value submitted with a time zone or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is processed by using that zone/offset to determine a value in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). That UTC value is then stored in the database, with a resolution of [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond) (not the milliseconds of legacy Java `java.util.Date` & `Calendar` classes, and not the [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) of java.time classes). After the UTC adjustment is made, the zone/offset information is discarded. If you care about the original zone/offset, store that in a separate column explicitly.

When retrieved, the date-time value is sent out from Postgres in UTC. An intervening tool such as [*psql*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#psql) or [*pgAdmin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#pgAdmin) may confusingly apply a default time zone. While well-intentioned, such a feature creates the illusion of the stored value carrying a time zone when in fact it does not. In contrast, a JDBC driver compliant with JDBC 4.2 and later will handle the UTC and zone automatically for you. Generally I suggest always retrieving a `Instant` object as shown in code above. Then apply zones if required to instantiate your own `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` objects as shown in code above.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw in the Postgres documentation for JDBC mapping types, Postgres expects a `java.sql.Timestamp` to be used to map to a timestamp with time zone type.  If you were working with a prepared statement, you could use this:

```
java.sql.Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(parsedTimeStamp.getTime());
PreparedStatement stmt;
// define the statement using Postgres SQL with placeholders
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
// now set the timestamp at the particular timezone in the statement
stmt.setTimestamp(index, ts, cal);
```

Replace `GMT` with whatever timezone you actually want, and replace `index` with the numerical index of the placeholder where the timestamp should appear in the actual SQL.

Note that more recent drivers which are Java 8 compliant should support using `LocalDateTime` in addition to `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: thanks! can you help translate this into non-preparestatement or is it not possible?

Comment: @KillerBeast Why aren't you using statements?  You should be using them, I think.

Comment: true but currently the project doesn't use prepared statements at all and in order to maintain uniformity i cant.

Comment: thanks for all the help. I understand the solution is better than the accepted solution but unfortunately, I can choose only one answer. Cant even upvote. So i am sticking to the other since it suits my requirements more. Thanks a ton anyways!